# How do I setup an ASP.NET project *WITHOUT* using the Visual Studio GUI?

Tags: .net, asp.net, emacs, mono

I'm using Emacs and Mono on Windows so that I can retain the same development environment while I'm in GNU/Linux.

So I need to know what the directory structure of an ASP.NET project and which files are critical to its operation (config files, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a web.config in the root dir as well as all of your aspx files.  The only other thing you really need will be a `bin` dir under the root to hold your assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

You only really need the Bin folder and web.config as someone mentioned already.

But if you are not using a web project (compiled site) then you'll need the App_Code folder to place your code files in so the site knows what to compile at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I would just make a templated project from the IDE and then use that every time you make a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/).

Comment: I'm not switching IDEs just to work on some projects. I'm asking for the directory structure/important-files list.

Comment: @omouse: It is a bit silly to go an use a text editor when you could use an IDE. Your choice though.

Comment: @Rich Mono has already been developed.  It's called the "kissing disease."

Comment: @BTK: Good thing you will never have to worry about getting that one!

Comment: Once Novell ship MonoDevelop for Windows, I guess it will be packaged in Mono installer too. Then you don't need to switch IDE from Emacs. You can just use MonoDevelop to create a project to start with.